# How to skip existing fields when unmarshal json in golang?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I use `json` file to configure my program arguments and use `flag` package to configure the same arguments.

When some argument parsed by `json` file and `flag` at the same time, I wish use the arguments parsed through `flag`.

The trouble is that the `json` file path is also parsed through `flag`.
The json path can be obtained after calling `flag.parse()`, but the arguments is also parsed, then `Unmarshal` json will overwrite the arguments of flag parsing.

example json:

```json
{
    "opt1": 1,
    "opt2": "hello"
}
```

example code:

```golang
var Config = struct {
    Opt1 int    `json:"opt1"`
    Opt2 string `json:"opt2"`
}{
    Opt1: 0,
    Opt2: "none",
}

func main() {

    // parse config file path
    var configFile string
    flag.StringVar(&configFile, "config", "", "config file path")

    // parse options
    flag.IntVar(&Config.Opt1, "opt1", Config.Opt1, "")
    flag.StringVar(&Config.Opt2, "opt2", Config.Opt2, "")

    // parse flags
    flag.Parse()

    // load config options from config.json file
    if configFile != "" {
        if data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFile); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("read config file error: %v\n", err)
        } else if err = json.Unmarshal(data, &Config); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("parse config file error: %v\n", err)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", Config)
}
```

program example output:
`./foo.exe -opt2 world`
out: `{Opt1:0 Opt2:world}`

`./foo.exe -config config.json`
out: `{Opt1:1 Opt2:hello}`

`./foo.exe -config config.json -opt2 world`
real out: `{Opt1:1 Opt2:hello}`
hope out: `{Opt1:1 Opt2:world}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution would be to first parse the JSON config file, and once that's done, then proceed to parse CLI arguments.

The problem with this is that the JSON config file is also a CLI arg.

The simplest solution would be to call `flag.Parse()` again after parsing the config file:

```
// load config options from config.json file
if configFile != "" {
    if data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configFile); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("read config file error: %v\n", err)
    } else if err = json.Unmarshal(data, &Config); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("parse config file error: %v\n", err)
    }

    // parse flags again to have precedence
    flag.Parse()
}
```

The second `flag.Parse()` will override and thus have precedence over data coming from the JSON file.

With this addition, running

```
./foo.exe -config config.json -opt2 world
```

Output will be what you desire:

```
{Opt1:1 Opt2:world}
```